# Ideal data structure for metabolic pathways

Tags: data-structures, bioinformatics

So I have a huge list of chemicals within an organism, with the data for both their precursor chemicals, and the ones they created.

I was thinking that some sort of tree structure would be appropriate; each chemical is a node, each parent is a precursor, each child is a product.

Each node could have more than one parent or more than one child, hence my confusion!

However, the main function in this structure will be to find ALL the chemical pathways to make it, and I'm not sure if a tree would be the most efficient at this sort of search.

My question is: is there a more appropriate data structure for this type of data and operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your data structure is a directed graph.

The brute-force approach for finding all the pathways from A to B would be to do a breadth-first search starting in A, and cover as much of the graph as you are allowed to.

This guarantees that the paths you'll find will be ordered in length from shortest to longest.

Whenever you hit B, you should mark all of the nodes in that path as 'leading to B'. This way you can account for convergent pathways without having to walk the graph more than once.

Keep in mind that, unless you constrain it, it can be posible for the graph to contain loops. A loop in a pathway leading from A to B presents you with infinite pathways, so it's up to you how you'd like to handle this cases.